# UICollectionView not able to scroll to see the entire last row

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView with size: `768x1024` with a navbar on top. My custom `UICollectionViewCells` are of size `200x200`. The problem is that when I keep adding cells and I reach the bottom row, I can only see part of the `200x200` cell. It won't let me scroll further before it bounces back up. Any ideas on what the problem could be?

EDIT:

I add cells via:

`insertItemsAtIndexPaths:`

Comment: Is your collection view's frame placing it off-screen?

Comment: Sort of, I can still see it, but I can't scroll all the way to the bottom of the cell

Comment: Have you tried making your frame smaller?

Comment: Your collection view's frame.

Comment: @AaronBrager, ah then no I haven't. What effect would this have?

Comment: @AaronBrager is suggesting that maybe the collection view's frame is bigger than the screen. Good idea. You should check the constraints/size of the collection view itself.

Answer (score 4):

The issue was just adding AutoLayout constraints to the View Controller which housed the `UICollectionView`. To do this, select the View Controller in Storyboards and click on "Editor" on the top. Then, "Resolve Autolayout Issues" > "Reset to Suggested Constraints..."

Comment: This can mashup with your constraints better to verify the collection view constraints. Might be your collection view Height is larger than the view controller.

Answer (score 4):

Check whether you have changed the minimum spacing attribute of collection view in size inspector of collection view. Setting it back to default values(10) was the solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has to do with your UICollectionViewLayout, since it is the job of the layout to state how large the actual scrollable content is, and to ask for a refresh of that information when necessary. But unfortunately your question reveals nothing about how you are doing layout or how you "keep adding cells", so no specific answer is possible.

EDIT (after your edit): It is not enough to call `insertItemsAtIndexPaths:`; you must also add the items to your model (the data source). Otherwise, the layout doesn't know about them and doesn't make the scrollable content bigger (and lots of other bad things happen too).

Comment: Sorry, it was hard to describe the interface.I I've added an edit in the original post. Is it possible to tell the layout, "scroll until the edge of the last element + a buffer" ?

Comment: The layout can do anything you want; you can write (or subclass) your own layout class. However, you are still not answering my implicit question; you have not even said what layout you are using!

Comment: I update my data source elsewhere. Also, I am not using any specific layout? (I think?) It's just a normal `UICollectionView`

Comment: Every collection view has a layout. You are probably using a UICollectionViewFlowLayout.

Answer (score 0):

i think you use the collection view in an unsual way, but if the content area of the scrollview of the collection view extend the frame size of the collection view you have to set the virtual size with the property 'contentSize' :

```
self.collectionView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(768,900);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't have an effect

Comment: problem is that you dont show up any code what you did. calling insertItemsAtIndexPaths id definitv not the correct way to populate a collection view cells. normally you would define a datasource and provide the correct datasource and delegate methods such as 'numberOfItemsInSection' and 'cellForItemAtIndexPath'.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but due a gradient that it was at the bottom of the collection view and the user was not able to see the last rows of the collection view.

The way I've found to solve it is in the Size Inspector, set the Height of the Footer Size to a number that works for issue.

I know that maybe, it's not the best solution. But it works for my problem and it's really easy to use it.

[Collection View that doesn't show the last row:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRTDD.png)

[Collection View after setting the Footer Size Height to 40:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Xx3X.png)

Comment: Hi... if you see this message can you please ping me back i need to ask something important.