# UICollectionView Not Showing Cells Completely. Last Cells Are Not Getting Shown Completely

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview, xcode6

I have created a custom gallery with collection view which shows all the Photos of camera roll from photos app. I have made a custom cell class. Now the thing is happening like below - : It is not showing my last row of cells. Please folks help me out with this.
It could be great for me. I am not using Constraints for my UICollectionView. I am not able to figure out ; how to give content size to UICollectionView like UIScrollView.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you add constraints to collection view?

Comment: Please check your constraints on collection view.

Comment: There is no constraints to my collection view. @MinkleGarg.

Comment: I am not using constraints for my collection view @aBilal17

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UICollectionView not able to scroll to see the entire last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21067091/uicollectionview-not-able-to-scroll-to-see-the-entire-last-row)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61289820/10505343 check whether this works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys some time problem seems way bigger than they looks.
I figure it out and yes it solved mine.

I was searching the simple and short solution for this and I found same related question below - :
[UICollectionView not able to scroll to see the entire last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21067091/uicollectionview-not-able-to-scroll-to-see-the-entire-last-row)

and the answer given by @Carpetfizz really worked for me.
I was using auto layout thats the reason it was solved ;
If you are not using auto layout it won't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Please enable Auto layout in your xib file

Answer (score -1):

If you are using constraints, create NSLayoutConstraint IBOutlet for height of collection view. Then do this thing

```
[collectionView reloadData];
layoutConstraintCollectionViewHeight.constant = collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize;

It will automatically resize you collection view height and can scroll upto last item.
```

For non-constraint design, use this

```
collectionView.frame = CGRectMake (x,y,w,h); // Here calculate your height and width for collection view 
[collectionView reloadData];
```

Comment: its not working @Pushkraj . I wanted to show every single bottom of cell like above.

Comment: Im using non-constraint dosing and it didn't work for me either